# Has 'ups and downs' been correctly used?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I want to say that life has moments of success as well as failure, moments when it's easy as well as moments when it's hard. In this context, has "ups and downs" been correctly used in the sentence below?

> Life has its own ups and downs.

If not, then kindly propose a correct, literary alternative.

Comment: Perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally correct to use it.

Answer (score 0):

100% correct. There is nothing wrong.